# Online glossary of Talmudic terms

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, internet, aramaic

Is there an online glossary anywhere that explains important Talmudic terms, with similar scope to the *[Practical Talmud Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873065883)*? I'm more interested in an Aramaic-English resource, but Aramaic-Hebrew would be useful as well.

Answer (score 7):

There's also the Jastrow online.

http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/

But that might be overkill, by the standards of Frank.

Comment: It's actually missing something that R' Frank provides, which is a treatment of common *phrases*, as used in context. But whoa! I didn't know this resource existed, and I'm very happy to see it.

Comment: Most (if not all) of the common phrases are also in Jastrow -- you just need to look them up under the key word of the given phrase (which granted isn't always easy to ascertain)

Comment: Has not been working at least for the past week (as of Aug 12 2018).  I found no contact on the domain.  Thanks @Shmuel_Goldstein the Wikisource one is good, and is digitized!

Answer (score 4):

i have a gemara glossary and a rashi glossary online
http://www.howtolearngemara.com/s/gemara-glossary/

http://www.howtolearngemara.com/s/rashi-glossary/

Comment: I'm getting a PHP error when I try to access the above link. Since you seem to own this site I figured you's want to know.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature) has **A Dictionary of the Targumim, the Talmud Babli and Yerushalmi, and the Midrashic Literature**

Comment: Note that this is a digitized version of Jastrow's dictionary, which was the subject of [@Curiouser's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7518/14850)

Answer (score 2):

For Aramaic/Hebrew, the [Aruch](http://books.google.com/books?id=viAQAAAAYAAJ&dq=%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false) and the [Maarich](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37548&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Also in the possible overkill category is *Yad Malachi*, which is [available freely and publicly](http://hebrewbooks.org/32530) on hebrewbooks.org and also included in the Bar Ilan database. It explains terms, logical structures, patterns, and methodology of the *G'mara*.

Answer (score 1):

Not comprehensive, but there's Hebrew Wiktionary's ["language of *Chazal*" category](http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%97%D7%96%22%D7%9C) and its subcategory ["lines from the Talmud"](http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D,_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%98%D7%95%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94).

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of Gemara words and their translation on E-chinuch.org.

You can link to it here: [Key Word List](http://www.chinuch.org/item_details.php?mid=1161&s=0)

On that website there are others that have key Gemara words explained in greater detail as well.

You will need to do a search which can be linked here: [Search of Gemara Words](http://www.chinuch.org/quick_search.php)