# What are some good resources for finding the meaning of unfamiliar Hebrew and Aramaic words in Acharonim?

Tags: words, torah-study, grammar-dikduk, language, dictionary

I have no trouble using [Jastrow](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/) for Tanach and Shas but I find it difficult to apply to Acharonim.  How might I use it more effectively?  Are there peculiarities of grammar I'm missing?

For a few examples, I'm looking now at some of the words that caused me to ask this question in the first place and I'm finding that with a little digging they are in fact generally in there.  I had been stuck on:

החוטין צריך שיהיו טווין לשמן

but I think I understand it now as "the threads should be twisted in groups of eight". In fact, I'm realizing that it could well be that what I really need is a stronger foundation in grammar and conjugation.  For example, I know what all of the words here mean:

הישן עם אשתו ובניו איך יתנהג

and I have a general sense of what this is saying, I think - "Customs regarding sleeping together with your wife and/or your children" - but why is נהג conjugated this way?  Doesn't the ית prefix indicate the infinitive?

Maybe my question is really "what is a solid resource for improving my understanding of grammar and conjugation", with a sub-question of "do the Acharonim generally conform to Mishnaic grammar?"

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7506/559

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. Am I perhaps not using Jastrow et al correctly if I am unable to use it effectively with the works of Acharonim?  When I come upon an unfamiliar phrase or word in Gemara I can find it easily. Not so with the aforementioned texts. This is what leads me to suspect that my problem may be one of parsing grammar.

Comment: Do you know how to find the shoresh/root of a word?

Comment: How about a few examples?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be closed as duplicate of the other, or reformulated to be about how best to use a dictionary like Jastrow's when studying _acharonim_.

Comment: @avi I thought that I did but maybe I don't.

Comment: @Gershon b"n I'll edit some in when I'm at my seforim.

Comment: @msh the latter sounds like my original intention, anyway.

Comment: yoel, then perhaps you should reword the question. I (and I guess @Curiouser, though perhaps not) thought you were largely duplicating that question.

Comment: Nicely edited, +1.

Comment: To address the actual examples you gave: לשמן means "for their name" - i.e., "for the sake of the mitzvah"; you've got the rest of the sentence correct. In the second one, ית is the reflexive, so יתנהג means "should conduct himself" - and again, your understanding of the rest of the sentence is correct: "How one should conduct himself when sleeping with his wife or children."

Comment: Yoel's translation of החוטין צריך שיהיו טווין לשמ is "the threads should be twisted in groups of eight". I believe that this is incorrect. There are (at least) two steps in preparing the wool for tzitzis. One is the טוויה or the spinning of the wool to create single threads. The other is the שזירה or the twisting of the single threads to create a thicker string that is used for the tzitzis. Thus the correct translation of Yoel's phrase is "The threads must be spun for the sake of tzitzis". As for the twisting of the thread to create a thicker string, ...

Comment: ... there is argument in the early halachic opinions as to whether it is required at all (Rambam says it isn't) or if it does, whether it requires to be done with the intent for tzitzis. The Aruch HaShulchan discusses this in great detail in siman 11 of Orach Chaim. Whether the twisting should be done with 2, 4 or 8 threads is yet another issue that is dealt with there.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was my initial understanding of לשמן but I was missing understanding it as "for the sake of the mitzva" as opposed to the plain meaning of "for the sake of the Name", although of course now that you bring it up I realize that the meanings are identical.

Comment: Very similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try taking a course in modern Hebrew grammar — which is pretty close to that used by the *Mishna* and to that used by the *acharonim* — or at least reading a book on it. Or on Biblical Hebrew grammar, which is also pretty close.

But here are a few pointers that will help you look things up in a dictionary:

- The following letters might appear at the beginning of a word, alone or in combination, without changing the root (some in Hebrew, some in Aramaic, some in both): אבדהויכלמנקשת.
- The following might appear in the middle of a word, i.e. among the letters of the root: וי. In addition, ת can appear after a ס or ש in a root, ט after a צ, and ד after a ז. And occasionally an א might be thrown in in the middle.
- The following letters might appear at the end of a word: אהויכמנת.

In addition, if a root is biliteral (or, which is the same thing, if it's triliteral with the second letter ו or י), you might see its last letter repeated.

So, for example, if you come across נסתובבתי, you might have to look under סוב. Of course, if you come across כשהתקדשתי, this answer doesn't help you at all — except its first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks!  Would you recommend a particular book?  Also, is the root of כשהתקדשתי not קדש?

Comment: I can't really recommend a particular book; perhaps someone else can (and you can switch the check mark form my answer to his!). The root of כשהתקדשתי _is_ קדש, but you can't tell that from the pointers I listed.

Comment: @yoel, I was also wondering what msh210 was up to by listing ק among the prefixes, until I remembered that it is used in Aramaic as a particle indicating the present tense - e.g., קמיפלגי, "they disagree" (from the root פלג, "split"), or קאמר, "he says" (from אמר).

Comment: "changing the root (some in Hebrew, some in Aramaic, some in both): אבדהויכלמנקשת"  hehe, sounds like you should just list the letters that are not prefixes :)

Comment: Hayesod Is a good book to learn modern hebrew grammar. http://www.amazon.com/Ha-yesod-Fundamentals-Hebrew-Luba-Uveeler/dp/0873062140